# How to Update the Datagridview Cell value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update the Particular Cell value by Clicking the button.This my Update function Code this is not Working. I want to know the correct Code

```
            try
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    cmd.CommandText =
                      "update  PatientDetails set PatientNumber= '" + pno.Text + "' and PatientName='" + pname.Text + "' and Age='" + age.Text + "' and Sex ='" + sex.Text + "' and PatientAddress='" + add.Text + "' and City='" + city.Text + "' and PhoneNumber='" + phone.Text + "' and EntryDate='" + edate.Text + "' and DoctorName='" + dname.Text + "' and Diagnosis='" + dig.Text + "' and  DepartmentName='" + dpname.Text + "' where PatientNumber ='" + dataGridView1.SelectedCells.ToString() + "', PatientName='" + dataGridView1.SelectedCells.ToString() + "' , Age='" + dataGridView1.SelectedCells.ToString() + "' ,  Sex ='" + dataGridView1.SelectedCells.ToString() + "' , PatientAddress='" + dataGridView1.SelectedCells.ToString() + "' , City='" + dataGridView1.SelectedCells.ToString() + "' , PhoneNumber='" + dataGridView1.SelectedCells.ToString() + "' , EntryDate='" + dataGridView1.SelectedCells.ToString() + "' . DoctorName='" + dataGridView1.SelectedCells.ToString() + "' ,Diagnosis='" + dataGridView1.SelectedCells.ToString() + "' ,  DepartmentName='" + dataGridView1.SelectedCells.ToString() + "'";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    cn.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
        } `
```

Comment: Well for starters, you may want to tell us what the error is?

Comment: What database are you using and what language is this? Have you profiled the database? What is the query being generated? Are you sure there aren't any exceptions being thrown? Have you interrogated `cmd.CommandText` to verify it contains the correct query? Can you run its the query in SQL?

Comment: What happens if you put "'; drop table PatientDetails;--" into pno.Text? Read up on SQL injection.

Comment: @Ghost I think he doesn't know about SQL injection

Comment: @The I think you might be right :)

Comment: I'm using C# with MS SQL !

Comment: when I put drop table and delete data also working here

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
update table_name
   set col1 = value1, col2 = value2, col3 = value3
 where col1 = value1 and col2 = value2 and col3 = value3
```

Not:

```
update table_name
   set col1 = value1 and col2 = value2 and col3 = value3
 where col1 = value1, col2 = value2, col3 = value3
```

Notice the difference in the use of commas (`,`), and the `and`s.

Comment: If you are not getting an exception, then the problem is that your `where` clauses are not matching with any row.  That's a data-specific problem that I can't help you with, because I can't see the data.  If you are getting an exception however, please provide the error information.